# how can I reference f.select tag id in rails to get value selected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am having trouble getting the id the value from a f.select tag in rails . I need to pass the value in javascript so i can perform a calculation but the html rendered does not have the id and the only value showing is the default no matter what I choose.

**in view**

```
<%= form_for([@event, @event.reservations.new]) do |f| %>

<div class="col m6 s12">
  <label for="Guests">Guests</label>
  <%= f.select :guests, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3", 3 ], ["4", 4 ], ["5", 5 ], ["6", 6 ], ["7", 7 ], ["8", 8 ], ["9", 9 ], ["10", 10 ], ["11", 11], ["12", 12 ], ["13", 13], ["14", 14], ["15+", 15 ]], id: "guests"   %>                   
</div>
```

**in javascript**

```
var guestSize = document.getElementById("guests").value;
```

This is what is being rendered in the html

```
<input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-9586aaf6-e36f-d805-3a71-7ba42d7bbec3" value="1">
```

No 'name' and 'id' showing up
.

Comment: can you edit with the html element on the rendered page?

Comment: am sorry i don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<%= f.select :guests, [["1",1], ["2",2], ["3", 3 ], ["4", 4 ], ["5", 5 ], ["6", 6 ], ["7", 7 ], ["8", 8 ], ["9", 9 ], ["10", 10 ], ["11", 11], ["12", 12 ], ["13", 13], ["14", 14], ["15+", 15 ]], {}, id: "guests"   %>
```

The empty hash as third argument may be relevant

Comment: Hey Thanks, it worked! you're a lifesaver. Why is an empty hash is required?

Comment: Will mark this as the answer as soon I have enough points to upvote

Comment: The method select has the format:
select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block). 
So you could pass as include_blank:true or another option you want, but if don't, just leave it blank as above. Thanks!